# Can not have element children within a simple type content

Tags: cognos, cognos-11

Using Cognos 11.0.13.1, but I have seen this problem reported as far back as 8.3.

I am getting this error message intermittently when I create a list that returns no results.  It happens both in page preview and when I run the report.

I have seen other posts about this and I am aware that the preferred solution is to update the *No data contents* property on an as-needed basis.  But I'm a Cognos administrator and I don't think this is an acceptable solution to push onto my users.

I see that when this happens, the Specified text is set to a string containing many (30?) spaces.  Or, perhaps, it's not spaces, it's a different white space character.

Where is the default value for *Specified text* set?  In the model?  In a configuration file?

As this is intermittent, is it related to some part of the system timing out before the entire session times out?

I have asked IBM Support, but as this is intermittent and I can't deliberately reproduce the problem, I'm not expecting much.

Update:
I don't remember seeing this problem again after upgrading to 11.1.7.  Perhaps it was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference: I was getting the same error in Cognos 11.1, suggest you to delete that report page/query and recreate page and query. you should copy your report to the clipboard as a backup.

More information on IBM help page: https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/rsv-srv-0003-report-specification-contains-error-line-line-column-col

Comment: Again -- not a good solution for thousands of users who are not IT folks.  And the link you provided is not related to the problem I am asking about.